# Can you see why texture isn't rendering? (Screenshots included)

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

Can you see why the texture isn't rendering? You can see that it's been UV mapped and appears on texture paint screen.

I've screen captured my materials and texture menus. Anything accidentally been checked or unchecked?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texture in your setup doesn't influence anything, so you need to enable **Color** checkbox in its settings.

Comment: Right on! I'd thought I'd tested toggling and rendering that checkbox to no avail but it worked when I tried it just now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Serge. Just to clarify:

[image]